# TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleCorrectAnswers' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I get an TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleCorrectAnswers' of undefined error.

```
this.handleCorrectAnswers = this.handleCorrectAnswers.bind(this)
handleCorrectAnswers(e){e.target.style.backgroundColor = "green"}
var endQuestions = ({wordList.map(function (word, index) {
    return (
        <button key={index} onClick= 
        {(e)=>this.handleCorrectAnswers(e)}>{word}</button>
    )})})}
```

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1):

Your error is in here.
`{wordList.map(function (word, index) { return ( <button key={index} onClick={(e) => this.handleCorrectAnswers(e)}>{word}</button> ) })}`

Inside functions(word, index){...}, 'this' is not what you are thinking.
Your error could be resolved by using a javascript arrow function.
like this.
`wordList.map((word, index) => { ... }` 
I wish it would be helpful for you.

Comment: Thank you sir! I didn't knew that

Comment: My pleasure. We are always helping each other in programming.